# How to extract dominant colors using palettes on RGB images?

Tags: python, colors, python-imaging-library, color-palette

I'm trying to build a module that can extract dominant colors from an image. For example, I'm trying to extract four colors from this flag image:

[image]

The `getpalette` and `getcolors` methods return `None`, if I try to use them in RGB mode. (I've tried setting `maxcolors`, I still get `None`.)

```
paletted = img.convert('RGB', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=4)
print(paletted.getpalette())
print(paletted.getcolors(maxcolors=256))
# None
# None
```

If I convert to `P` mode, I can use these modules, but I lose the yellow.

```
paletted = img.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=4)
paletted.show()
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the following doesn't work, or to be precise, is simply ignored:

```py
paletted = img.convert('RGB', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=4)
```

From the documentation on [`Image.convert`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert):

> **palette** – Palette to use when converting from mode "RGB" to "P". Available palettes are `WEB` or `ADAPTIVE`.

You're converting from `RGB` to `RGB`, thus the `palette` and `colors` parameters are ignored.

Next issue, which also prevents the proper conversion to mode `P`: You have a JPG image with JPG artifacts. Your image contains a lot more colors than you might expect. From the documentation on [`Image.getcolors`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getcolors):

> **maxcolors** – Maximum number of colors. If this number is exceeded, this method returns None. The default limit is 256 colors.

Increase `maxcolors` (the possible maximum number of different colors for some full 24 bit RGB image is 2<sup>24</sup>), and check the four most prominent colors:

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('47ckF.jpg')
n_dom_colors = 4
dom_colors = sorted(img.getcolors(2 ** 24), reverse=True)[:n_dom_colors]
print(dom_colors)
# [(135779, (0, 0, 0)), (132476, (0, 0, 254)), (109155, (254, 0, 0)), (2892, (251, 2, 0))]
```

You get solid black, nearly solid blue, nearly solid red, and a variant of red. Where's yellow? JPG artifacts! You have a ton of black-ish, blue-ish, and red-ish colors, which are all more prominent than the first yellow-ish color. For example, even setting `n_dom_colors = 20` won't show you the first yellow-ish color.

How to achieve, what you might have in mind? Have a look at [`Image.quantize`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.quantize), which will give you a mode `P` image using color quantization:

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('47ckF.jpg')
img = img.quantize(colors=4, kmeans=4).convert('RGB')
n_dom_colors = 4
dom_colors = sorted(img.getcolors(2 ** 24), reverse=True)[:n_dom_colors]
print(dom_colors)
# [(139872, (1, 0, 1)), (138350, (0, 0, 253)), (134957, (252, 1, 1)), (3321, (253, 240, 12))]
```

You get nearly solid black, nearly solid blue, nearly solid red, and a yellow variant!

For reference, the quantized and re-converted image:

[image: Quantized]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
Pillow:        8.2.0
----------------------------------------
```